# Using Google Cloud Speech on mobile never returns an isFinal

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-speech

I am currently implementing a ChatBot using Google Cloud Speech.

I am using socket.io to record a microphone stream and then sending that through node to Google Cloud Speech.

Everything is working fine on my laptop and my android mobile phone (Nexus 5x, Chrome 68)
I record the audio, and having set single_utterance to true, get a result with "isFinal" as soon as I pause speaking.

But if I set the language code to 'da-DK', I never get a "isFinal" result (unless I end the stream myself) on mobile. Works fine on my laptop, but not mobile.

Have anyone experienced anything similar?

As a bonus info:
If I set interimResults to true, I do get multiple results, but they are just never isFinal.

So just to be clear: everything is working perfectly apart from the one case: da-DK on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

As this behavior is occurring only when using the `da-DK` [supported language](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages) on a mobile device, it might be related to an internal service issue; therefore, I think that you should take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#bug_reports) tool that you can use to raise a [Speech-to-Text API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187181&template=0) in order to verify this scenario with the Google Technical Support Team. In this way, you will be able to share your code, audio files and internal project information if required by the troubleshooting process.

Additionally, I suggest you to take a look on this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech) that contains some useful documentation and example to use Google Cloud Speech API on an Android environment that you may use as a reference for your project.